# For some reason this errors and won't register my users

Tags: php, pdo

```
$encrypt1 = hash('sha512',$password);
$encrypt = hash('sha512',$encrypt1);
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
$_SESSION['password'] = $encrypt;
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$data1 = "INSERT INTO users username, password, email, ip VALUES :username,:password,:email,:ip";
$data2 = $handler->prepare($data1);
$data2->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $encrypt, ':email' => $email, ':ip' => $ip));
echo "<div class='reg-success'><p class='basic-font reg-success-txt'>You         have been successfully registered - Redirecting Momentarily</p></div>";
header('Refresh: 5; URL=../');
```

i believe the error is somewhere in this code
i think i made an error in the prepare or execute statement

Comment: You're missing brackets in `$data1` - Edit: You can disregard this comment.

Comment: This will serve you *much* better => [`PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: Stop assuming that your queries will never fail. **ALWAYS** assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise. If you'd had even basic minimal error handling, you'd have been told about your SQL syntax errors.

Comment: las vegas would love OP. "1 in infinity odds? Lemme mortgage my house"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$data1 = "INSERT INTO users username, password, email, ip  
          VALUES :username,:password,:email,:ip";
```

should be:

```
$data1 = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, ip) 
          VALUES (:username,:password,:email,:ip)";
```

Answer (score 4):

`INSERT` requires parentheses around the list of columns and values:

```
$data1 = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, ip)
          VALUES (:username,:password,:email,:ip)";
```